# Two 16 bit ints to One 32 bit float value

Tags: java, algorithm, floating-point, int, modbus

I am able to extract values from modbus as 16-bit shorts (unsigned) or as ints (should be treated as 16-bit words). I am tasked to combine two values to create a single 32 bit float value using java.

some example values I observed using a gui program:

- int + int = float
- 0 + 16256 = 1
- 0 + 17096 = 100
- 0 + 17097 = 100.5
- 0 + 17530 = 1000
- 8192 + 17530 = 1000.5

I attempted bit wise operators but that didn't seem to do the trick.
leaves me scratching my head!

Comment: what does `combining` mean? Add to integers and represent as float or use the bit-pattern of two 16-bit integers to create a 32-bit pattern treated as float?

Comment: is not int + int a long?

Comment: It could be as simple as `65535.0F*int1+int2` but without a proper problem statement it is impossible to really answer your question.

Comment: I have the following methods int getValue() and short toUnsignedShort(). I am not sure on the conversion. my documentation simple states convert each register pair to a float value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Float.intBitsToFloat(int bits)` to build a `float` from the bits of an `int`.

```
short high = ... // the high 16 bits
short low = ... // the low 16 bits
int combined = (high << 16) | low;
float num = Float.intBitsToFloat(combined);
```

for example:

```
short high = 17530;
short low = 8192;
```

produces the float `1000.5`.