# How to Convert 32 bit float value to two 16 bit integers

Tags: java

I have a question that ***How to Convert 32 bit float value to two 16 bit integers***.

Actually Im converting two 16 bits integers into 32 - bit float.

from the reference of [two-16-bit-ints-to-one-32-bit-float-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908820/two-16-bit-ints-to-one-32-bit-float-value)

But i need one 32 bit float to two 16 bit ints.Any one Help me.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: To clarify: you want to have the 16 bit integers when concatenated to have the same 32 bit pattern then the float value?

Comment: From float value i need two 16 bit ints ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do the trick

```
float f = 107.5f; // the float value
int v = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
int i1 = (v >> 16) & 0xffff;
int i2 = v & 0xffff;
```

giving the two 16 bit quantities `i1` and `i2`.

Comment: Thank you @henry. this also worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
int value = Float.floatToRawIntBits(Float.valueOf("1074563458561.34").floatValue());
int value1 = value >>> 16;
int value2 = value << 16 >>> 16;
System.out.println(String.format("%d %d", value1, value2));
```

> 21370 12537

Comment: You were slightly faster than me.

Comment: Yours is more elegant though. Will rate you up :)

Comment: You should use logical shift right `>>>` to make it actually correct.

Comment: I do not see the difference, can you explain?

Comment: If the sign bit is 1 there is a difference. `>>` would copy the sign bit on the left side, while `>>>` would shift in zeroes.

Comment: Thanks, did not know. Admittedly methods like this require abundant test coverage :)